# Core Animation circle animation

Tags: ios, rotation, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have been trying to make a circular CALayer to simply rotate on its center. I have only been able to make it rotate it on a wrong anchor point. I have tried to change this anchor point but the animation keeps the same.

```
- (void)rotateImage {
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: -M_PI*2];
rotationAnimation.duration = 1;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[self.surroundingCircles addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Result : https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmlxw1t2mle0au9/rotation.mov?dl=0

Comment: How did you set the anchor point?

Comment: self.surroundingCircles.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

Comment: try setting the center of the view you are turning: `self.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));`

Comment: I am using a CAShapeLayer and not a view.

Answer (score 2):

I had to set the frame of the layer first:

`self.surroundingCircles.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22);`